# Non-linear secondary x axis matlab

Tags: matlab, plot

I am trying to plot a y vs x graph.  The x is a time vector.  However, at different (irregular times) there is a second vector k (engine hours) that will change.

For instance:

```
t = [1:1:10];
k = [1 1 2 2 2 2 2 5 8 8];
```

`t` and `k` are the same length.

However, on my y vs t graph, I want a second x axis (driven by the t vector) that shows change in k.  For instance at `t = 1`, `k = 1`,... then we see a new value at `t = 3`, `k = 1`.

How can I create a second axis like this?

Comment: Could you please provide a diagram/drawing/illustration of the desired result? You can upload it someplace like [imgur](http://imgur.com/) and post us a link.

Answer (score 0):

I dont clearly understand, but try this

```
nk = [0,diff(k)];
```

Comment: My intent was to produce an additional x-axis on the y vs t plot.

Answer (score 0):

The question was a little difficult for me to understand... but I'll give it a try.

You want 2 graphs plotted in the same figure.

- ***y vs t***
- *"a second x axis (driven by the t vector) that shows change in k"*, so **k vs t**

It sounds like you want a plot with 2 y-axes over a single x-axis.  You can use the [plotyy](http://nl.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/plotyy.html) function for this, here's an example:

```
y = sin(0:2*pi/9:2*pi);
t = [1:10];
k = [1 1 2 2 2 2 2 5 8 8];

figure(1);

[ax1,h1,h2] = plotyy(t,y,t,k);
xlabel('time');
ylabel(ax1(1),'y');
ylabel(ax1(2),'engine hours');
```

[image: Example of code output]

Is this what you were going for?  Or did you mean you are trying to make an additional x-axis on the **y vs t** plot, where the t values are replaced with their corresponding k values (i.e. A single line going through your plot which corresponds to 2 different x-axes as well as an y-axis)?

To do this you can try making an extra plot with the x-axis on top and manually label the x-ticks with `k`, then create a new axes and plot your **y vs t** graph on top of it.  The following code gives an example:

```
y = sin(0:2*pi/9:2*pi);
t = [1:10];
k = [1 1 2 2 2 2 2 5 8 8];

% Clear old figure
try
    close 1;
end
figure(1);
%% Create t vs k plot (upper x axis)
axes();
plot(t,y);
set(gca,'xaxislocation','top','yticklabel',[],'xticklabel',k);
xlabel('Engine Hours');
hold on;
%% Create t vs y plot
axes()
plot(t,y);
xlabel('time');
ylabel('y');
set(gca,'xaxislocation','bottom');
```

Which results in this:
[image]

Comment: Thanks! My initial intent was to make an additional x-axis on the y vs t plot.

Comment: Ah, K.  I've updated my answer to cover what I think your original question was now.  Is this what you were going for?